# Как сохранить измененный массив при выходе из программы

Tags: java

Есть постоянная переменная `as` массива:

```
List<String> as = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d"));
```

В процессе работы элементы массива добавляются и удаляются. Как сохранить измененный массив при выходе из программы?

У меня на данный момент при запуске программы массив инициализируется в первоначальном виде. Какой командой сохранить новые элементы («a», «e», «z») в переменную `as`?

Comment: Вариантов много:
1. в базу
2. в файл(посмотрите в сторону сериализации)

Comment: это понятно, я хотел  сохранить новые элементы в переменную as

Comment: Что значит "сохранить новые переменные"?
Вот пример сохранение всего массива в файл и его заполнения из файла:
int[] az = {10, 20, 30};
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
  new FileOutputStream("filename")) ;
oos.writeObject(az);
oos.flush();
oos.close();

ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
  new FileInputStream("filename"));
  int[] az = (int[])ois.readObject();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед завершением выполняете это:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream("filename")) ; 
oos.writeObject(as);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

При открытии делаете это:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( new FileInputStream("filename")); 
as = (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
ois.close()
```

Comment: огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Когда программа завершается после окончания или принудительно то вся память освобождается. Поэтому, как сказал Arhad, чтобы возобновить состояние `ArrayList`  нужно или достать объект из базы, либо из файла, я так понимаю это сериализация и десериализация объекта.

Ну а чтобы достать нужно вначале сохранить.

в переменную `as` можно сохранить командой `as.add("ololo");`

Comment: я просто с базами ещё не работал

Comment: если я правильно понял, вопрос состоял в следующем "как добавить элемент в список"??? у меня только один комментарий Б@#$, дожились...

Comment: Не он имел ввиду сохранить куда-то, просто затупил с объяснением немного.